# The current request is not multipart request

Tags: java, jquery, jsp

> Below is my code:
>   jsp code

```
<form:form name="uploadForm" id="fileUploadForm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file" value="Import"  ">
    <input type = "hidden" name="strategy" />
    <input type="button" value="Import" id="Import" /> 
</form:form>
```

> Below jquery snippet binds the click function of the Import button

```
$("#Import").click(function(){
    filePath = document.getElementById("file").value;
}
```

> The filePath value is getting assigned in the above variable filePath
>    Below piece of code makes an Ajax call to the controller

```
var formData = new FormData($('#fileUploadForm')[0]);
formData.append('tax_file', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]); 
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/getuploadFile.html',
    data: {
        formData:formData, strategy:strategy,
    },
    type: "POST",
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success : function(response){
        alert(response); 
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("Inside"); 
    }
});
```

> java controller class

```
@RequestMapping(value = "ajax/getuploadFile.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String getuploadFile(HttpServletRequest request,
                @RequestParam("formData") MultipartFile attachment, 
                @RequestParam("strategy") String strategy,
                ) throws Exception {
```

> Can anyone please help me.. I am facing the exception that current request is not multipart request. We are trying to import .csv file through import functionality mentioned in jsp code.

Comment: add content-type as 'multipart/form-data' and check.

Comment: I am not able to find out.. Can you please guide me.. I need help..Not able to proceed further.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this way:

**Java controller**

```
@Controller
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping("/test")
    @ResponseBody
    public String upload(

            @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile multipartFile,

            @RequestParam("strategy") String strategy) {

        return "ok";
    }

    @RequestMapping
    public ModelAndView index() {
        return new ModelAndView("/WEB-INF/jsp/upload.jsp");
    }
}
```

**JSP file**

```
<html>
<body>
    <form name="uploadForm" id="fileUploadForm" method="POST"enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" id="file" name="file" value="Import""> 
        <input type="hidden" name="strategy" /> 
        <input type="submit" value="Import" id="Import" />
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('form[name="uploadForm"]').submit(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var formData = new FormData($('#fileUploadForm')[0]);
            formData.append('file', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]); 
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: '/test',
                                    data: formData,
                                    type: "POST",
                                    contentType: false,
                                    processData: false,
                                    success : function(response){
                                        alert(response); 
                                    },
                                    error: function() {
                                        alert("Inside"); 
                                    }
                                });
            return false;
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to test it. It's working well.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134779/discussion-on-answer-by-huy-ta-the-current-request-is-not-multipart-request).

Answer (score 0):

"formData" already contain "file" and "strategy", so you just need: `data: formData`

```
var formData = new FormData($('#fileUploadForm')[0]);
    formData.append('tax_file', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]); 
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'ajax/getuploadFile.html',
                        data: formData,
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                       success : function(response){
                            alert(response); 
                            },
                    error: function() {
                         alert("Inside"); 
                 }
```

Comment: Thank You for quick answer.. But strategy is the hidden value I need to take to the controller.Please advice.. How I can proceed..

Comment: Hi I have analysed that the below file tag which i am using.. when i am placing that tag in from it is not returning the json response can anyone please help me.. <input type="file" id="file" name="file" value="Import"">..Please help me i am not able to proceed further